# SQL query for joining five tables with conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, left-join, inner-join

I have 5 tables looks like following:

```
Serial_Number|Product_ID|Mfg_ID|Distribution_Type
AG0026       | CKJUT    |UGXT03|A
BX3234       | NPLPT    |UXXP32|B
LP3269       | KNGTP    |AKML63|A
.....         .....      ...    ..
```

ProductDetails2:

```
Serial_Number|Product_Type|Unit
NG2164       |S           |10
LT4598       |L           |13
BX3234       |L           |21
```

Mfgaccnt:

```
SLNO|Product_Code|Mfg_Code
1   |T03         |T03
2   |L63         |L63
3   |BXT         |null
```

MfgDetails1:

```
mfg_code|Mfg_Name
T03         | xy.pvt.ltd
L63         | LP.pvt.ltd
```

MfgDetails2:

```
Sel_ID|Mfg_Name
UXXP32|ab.pvt.ltd
NTLP25|cd.pvt.ltd
```

Now I need to generate a report where I need following column

1. Serial_Number
2. Product_ID
3. Mfd_ID where product type is L
4. Mfg_Name where product type is L
5. Unit where product type is L

Conditions:

1. Product_code of MfgDetails1= Last 3 digit of Mfg_ID of ProductDetails1
2. Sel_ID of MfgDetails2= Mfg_ID of ProductDetails1
3. If distribution_type = 'A', then for the mfg details. You need to take the last 3 characters of mfg_ID of ProductDetails1, look that up as the product_code on mfgacct to find the mfg_code, then use that mfg_code to access MfgDetails1 for mfg_name.
4. If distribution_type = 'B', then for the mfg details.You need to take the full mfg_ID of ProductDetails1, and look that up as the Sel_ID on MfgDetails2.

So my query:

```
SELECT 
    pd1.serial_number AS 'Serial Number',Pd1.product_ID AS 'Product ID', 
    pd1.mfg_id,
    CASE WHEN pd1.distribution_type='A' THEN md1.Mfg_Name 
         ELSE md2.Mfg_Name 
    END AS 'MFG Name',
    pd1.distribution_type,
    pd2.unit
FROM   
    ProductDetails1 pd1 
JOIN 
    ProductDetails2 pd2 ON pd1.serial_number = pd2.serial_number 
JOIN   
    Mfgaccnt ON Mfgaccnt.Product_Code = Right(Pd1.Mfg_ID,3)
JOIN  
    MfgDetails1 ON Md1.Mfg_Code = Mfgaccnt.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN 
    MfgDetails2 md2 ON pd1.mfg_Id = md2.sel_ID
WHERE
    pd2.product_type = 'L'
```

But Result isn't returning any B distribution type products. Please help me out

Comment: I am unable to format. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar (or just indent your lines by at least 4 characters!) to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Well isn't this the problem:

- If distribution_type = 'A', then for the mfg details. You need to
  take the last 3 characters of mfg_ID of ProductDetails1, look that up
  as the product_code on mfgacct to find the mfg_code, then use that
  mfg_code to access MfgDetails1 for mfg_name.

In your SQL you're doing that also for other distribution types:

```
JOIN   
    Mfgaccnt ON Mfgaccnt.Product_Code = Right(Pd1.Mfg_ID,3)
```

Since that is not a left outer join, it will filter out all the rows that do not get a match that way.